# Populating a go struct with sub object data

Tags: go

I have a Project struct and in there there should be project details but also the Owner object, so something like:

```
type User struct {
   Id   int    `json:"id"`
   Name string `json:"name"`
}
type Project struct {
   Name      string    `json:"name"`
   StartDate time.Time `json:"startDate"`
   Owner     User      `json:"owner"`
}
```

So the object returned to the front end has the owners user data in the Project. In Go, is there a way to query for this simply? Or do I have to do something like querying for the project data joined with the owner data and then building the Project object by iterating over the results of that query or something. Ive done this in the past but not in a long while and cant remember for the life of me how to do it.

Comment: The answer depends on where you are querying it from. What you suggested is a way of querying it from a relational db, and what you described is a way of doing it. Note that in this case, you only need the first row of the resultset.